# Change background color of highest number in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a table, and I want the highest number in each column to have a yellow background. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Here you can see the code of my table:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Naam)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Bier)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Frisdrank)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Chips)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Naam, "Details", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bier)
            @{AantalBier += item.Bier;}
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Frisdrank)
            @{AantalFrisdrank += item.Frisdrank;}
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Chips)
            @{AantalChips += item.Chips;}
        </td>
    </tr>
}
    <tr style="background-color:#d9e6c4">
        <th>
            Totaal
        </th>
        <th>
            @AantalBier
        </th>
        <th>
            @AantalFrisdrank
        </th>
        <th>
            @AantalChips
        </th>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: You could use a `ViewModel` representing your domain model for display purpose and figuring out what is the highest number for you, then make it set the table cell for you through a property or the like, or simply use a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would sort the model using the `OrderBy` linq extension method, then the highest value would come to the top of the table and I'd highlight the first row.

However if you don't want to sort the model for some reason, you can check if the value is the max by calling the `Max` method.

For instance:

```
foreach (var i in Model){
     if (i.Number == Model.Max(x=> x.Number))
        <td style="background:yellow">Something</td>
     else 
         <td>Something</td>
}
```